# Solr field name rules?

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

Sorry for the newby question, I'm new to Solr. In managed-schema, I see that there are many fields with identical types but different names. How does Solr identify which field to store the tokens given that the types are all the same but only names are different? For instance,

```
<field name="content_type" type="text_general">
<field name="content_type_hint" type="text_general">
<field name="blitz" type="text_general">
```

They all the have the same type (same analyzer). How does Solr store different content into all these text_general fields? Do they check the names of tags with the actual content? and if not identical, it moves on to dynamic fields? I searched on the web and it seems no one has mentioned in detail if name helps in the process of indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So names and type are two different things.

```
<field name="content_type" type="text_general">
```

In the above case the name of the field is "content_type" which will be used to search it.

e.g if you want to search a docuemnt with content_type="xml", you will query something like this

> q=content_type:xml

however type defines the analysis that will occur on a field when documents are indexed or queries are sent to the index.

so somewhere in your schema you will have defined the field type text_general something like this.

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
```

You can read more about it here
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/field-type-definitions-and-properties.html

Solr wont store everything into the type field. type field just tells it what analysis to run on the field while indexing or querying. 
Every field will have its own index.

Edit:
i think you are confused how data is indexed. Lets take an example of.

lets say i have a document like this

> {
>
> ```
>   "content_type" : "text/html",   
>     "content_type_hint" : "some_hint",
>     "blitz" : "some_text"
> ```
>
> }

So when you index the document you will tell solr which field you are putting what value.

so in this case you are saying the field `content_type` has value `"text/html"` and `blitz` has value `"some_text"`.

Then solr will do some analysis based on what the type of that field is and then put it to respective index.

Comment: So is name used in breaking down the html field? For instance, if a field is named "content_type", would Tika/Solr actually go search for the name "content_type"? Because I see there are a lot of custom names such as "twitter_creator" in schema file. When indexed and queried, the output does include the correct twitter_creator in the field. So during the indexing process, the program actually looks for these words?

Comment: hi, I re-read your answer and believe that you have not answered my question.... My question does not lie in field type analyzer. My question is whether the name property in field (not field type) matters in breaking down html. For instance, you mentioned content_type as a name. So when I define a field with name content_type, does Solr look for content_type in the html page? In other words, do names play a role in finding what belongs to this field? How does Solr know where to find content_type based only on analyzer?

Comment: So i am not sure what you mean by html page. you need to tell solr what goes in which field. When you index a document you will say i want to add this text in this field. Does that make sense ?

Comment: right. The confusion part to me is that how does Solr know which part of the text goes to which fields given multiple fields have the same analyzer but different names? Does Solr search the name attribute in tags such that the name attribute value matches the field name?

Comment: You tell solr which text go to which field by name of the field. This happens during index time.

Comment: So Solr maps name attribute of tags on the html page with the name I give in the fields?

Comment: How are you ingesting data into solr right now? Can you show me what are you trying to index?hows your html looks like?

Comment: The examples are given in the question. That three fields are taken from the default managed_schema file. As you can see, all of them are of type text_general but they have different names. So does Solr check on the names to know which text to be put into which field?

Comment: Yes . Based on the name of the field it will index data.

Comment: Lets say there is a html file, does Solr look at the name attribute of tags to match name attribute of the field? This bit is my final confusion.